# Jquery change value of field dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

A user selects a start date, and 'on change' I want to populate the corresponding end date.

This is not working, any ideas why?  The alerts look fine but the last line is not working:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.input-group.date').change(function() {
            var $input = $(this).find('input.form-control');
            alert($input.attr('id'));
            alert($input.val());

            var $effdateid = $input.attr('id')
            var expdateid =  $effdateid.replace("effective","expire")

            alert(expdateid) //this is the target field id
            $(expdateid).val($input.val())

        })
    });
```

Comment: You'll need to put a # in front of your id. $("#" + expdateid).val($input.val())

Comment: ↑↑↑↑  This ↑↑↑↑  You're missing the hash in front of the element id.